# Executing code in overloaded constructor prior to calling this()

Tags: scala, constructor, overloading

Say we have a class like this:

```
import java.net.URL
import xml._

class SearchData(xml: Node) {
  def this(url: URL) = this (XML.load(url))
}
```

and we want to execute some code prior to calling `this (XML.load(url))` - say test it with `try`. One would expect that writing something like this would work:

```
class SearchData(xml: Node) {
  def this(url: URL) {
    try {
        this (XML.load(url))
    } catch {
      case _ => this(<results/>)
    }
  }
}
```

but it won't, because Scala requires that you make the call to `this()` the first statement in the overloaded constructor and in this case `try` becomes the first statement.

So what would be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def this(url: Url) = this(try {XML.load(url)} catch {case _ => <results/>})
```

More generally, the evaluation of the arguments has to happen before the constructor call, so you do that there (**a block in scala is an expression**, but write a routine, typically written in the companion object, if it is going to be too long). What you cannot do is have this code choose which other constructor you call. But as all of them must route to the primary one, you do not lose much. Also, you need the other constructor you call to have at least one argument. If there are several constructors, the primary one should normally not be the one without an argument (see [Scala problem optional constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203292/scala-problem-optional-constructor/7203393#7203393))

Comment: A good solution for the declared problem, but it's not general. Probably it's my fault that I declared a misleadingly trivial problem. Anyway check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680442/executing-code-in-overloaded-constructor-prior-to-calling-this/7687567#7687567 which somewhat evolves your solution

Answer (score 5):

A factory method in companion object:

```
object SearchData {
  def apply(xml: Node) = new SearchData(xml) //Added to provide uniform factories
  def apply(url: URL) = {
    try {
      new SearchData(XML.load(url))
    } catch {
      case _ => new SearchData(<results/>)
    }
  }
}

//Example
val sd = SearchData( new URL( "http://example.com/" ) )
```

Not only it simplifies design, but you can spare the `new` keyword.

Comment: I don't see how it simplifies design. It also forces you to either introduce inconsistency by constructing objects both with and without the `new` keyword depending on scenario or violate the DRY rule and create companion aliases for all constructors in your classes icluding main ones so that you could construct without `new` always. And yet still you will always have to construct library classes with `new`.

Comment: Actually the pattern is quite common in the scala library, and automatically implemented for case classes. So the _inconsistency_ is there already. Plus the strong drawbacks that constructor tells too much to the client most of the time, namely the exact type of the result and the fact that it is newly created. A factory is not worth doing all the time, but they are often convenient and while it does bother me, I would not stop at the inconsistency. I remember fondly Delphi where constructors and static functions where called just the same way from the client.

Comment: I agree with you totally. Actually in [Kotlin](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Classes+and+Inheritance) they solve this problem by getting rid of the `new` keyword at all. It's just strange for me that Scala guys don't see a problem here.

Comment: It simplifies the design, because there is just one way of building an object: _the_ constructor. So no problem about calling it first... That kind of factories are just syntactical sugar to spare the user extra compulsory steps. BTW, I updated the code to solve the _inconsistency_.

Answer (score 3):

While didierd's solution solves the declared problem and is somewhat close to this one, it still doesn't solve the problem when you have to execute several statements prior to calling `this`. This one provides a general approach to all scenarios:

```
class SearchData(xml: Node) {
  def this(url: URL) = this {
    println(url)
    try {
      XML.load(url)
    } catch {
      case _ => <results/>
    }
  }
}
```

The trick here is that `this` is fed with result of executing an anonymous function in body of which you are allowed to do anything.

But this only works when you have a single-argument main constructor - in other scenarios you will have to introduce a `Tuple`-based workaround:

```
class SearchData(xml: Node, valid: Boolean) {
  def this(url: URL) = this {
    println(url)
    try {
      (XML.load(url), true)
    } catch {
      case _ => (<results/>, false)
    }
  }
  def this(t: (Node, Boolean)) = this(t._1, t._2)
}
```

Comment: I think my comments covered your first case with println. But you make a very good point with the second case.