# Cannot create constructor with logic in Scala program?

Tags: scala, constructor

I have the following program:

```
 class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  require(d != 0)
  private val g = gcd(n.abs, d.abs)
  val numer = n / g
  val denom = d / g
  def this(n: Int) = this(n, 1)
  def this(s: String) = {
    val regex: Regex = "^([+-]?(\\d+|\\d*\\.?\\d+)|\\d*\\/?\\d+)$".r
    if (!regex.matches(s)) throw new NumberFormatException()
    val input: Array[String] = s.split("\\.|\\/")
    val num: Int = input(0).toInt
    if (input.length equals 1)
      this(num, 1) // problem here
    else
      this(num, input(1).toInt) // problem here
  }
}
```

I tried to create the constructor with some logic. However, I cannot due to

> 'Rational' does not take parameters

What's the problem?

Comment: What version of Scala are you using? It doesn't even compile the `this(n: String)`, because it expects a `this`-invocation as the first expression. Also, I have the feeling that `this`-constructors are pretty much out of fashion, defining `apply` on `object Rational` would be much more idiomatic.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The code you posted *cannot possibly* lead to the error you posted. Please make sure to construct a [mre] which *accurately represents your exact problem*. Note that all three of those words are important: it should be an *example* only, you should not post your entire actual code, rather you should create a simplified example that demonstrates your problem. Also, it should be *minimal*, i.e. it should not contain anything that is not absolutely required to demonstrate the problem. (Most beginner problems can be demonstrated in less than 5 short simple lines …

Comment: … of code. I don't understand what your problem is, but at least the error message I am seeing with your code can be reproduced in 3 lines.) And it should be *reproducible*, which means that if I copy&paste and run the code, I should see the exact same problem you see. (Which is not the case with your code. I see a different error than the one you posted.) https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to introduce a helper method

```scala
import scala.util.matching.Regex

def gcd(i: Int, i1: Int): Int = BigInt(i).gcd(BigInt(i1)).toInt

class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  require(d != 0)
  private val g = gcd(n.abs, d.abs)
  val numer = n / g
  val denom = d / g

  def this(n: Int) = this(n, 1)

  def this(s: String) = {
    this(Rational.transformStr(s)._1, Rational.transformStr(s)._2)
  }
}

object Rational {
  // helper method
  def transformStr(s: String): (Int, Int) = {
    val regex: Regex = "^([+-]?(\\d+|\\d*\\.?\\d+)|\\d*\\/?\\d+)$".r
    if (!regex.matches(s)) throw new NumberFormatException()
    val input: Array[String] = s.split("\\.|\\/")
    val num: Int = input(0).toInt
    if (input.length equals 1)
      (num, 1)
    else
      (num, input(1).toInt)
  }
}
```

or better, factory methods (because constructors have many limitations)

```scala
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int) {
  require(d != 0)
  private val g = gcd(n.abs, d.abs)
  val numer = n / g
  val denom = d / g
}

object Rational {
  // factory methods
  def apply(n: Int) = new Rational(n, 1)

  def apply(s: String): Rational = {
    val regex: Regex = "^([+-]?(\\d+|\\d*\\.?\\d+)|\\d*\\/?\\d+)$".r
    if (!regex.matches(s)) throw new NumberFormatException()
    val input: Array[String] = s.split("\\.|\\/")
    val num: Int = input(0).toInt
    if (input.length equals 1)
      new Rational(num, 1)
    else
      new Rational(num, input(1).toInt)
  }
}
```

[Executing code in overloaded constructor prior to calling this()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680442/executing-code-in-overloaded-constructor-prior-to-calling-this)

By the way, you can also use default values

```scala
class Rational(n: Int, d: Int = 1 /*default*/ ) {
  // ...
}

object Rational {
  def apply(s: String): Rational = ???
}
```